# How can I get all quote which is active with customer ID

Tags: customer, quote, customer-session, factory, customer-collection

Is there anyway I could print out in a table in phtml the following:
Entity_id , is_active and store 
Is it possible to get all active quote within a customer_id?

I want to show this in a table 
I was taking a look at quote DB and I can see all the details there but not sure how to show this in a phtml

Answer (score 2):

To get quote items of a customer please use below code. You can pass customer object also in place of customer id.

```
<?php 
protected $quoteModel;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote $quoteModel
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteModel=$quoteModel;
    ....

}

$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
$customerQuote=$this->quoteModel->loadByCustomerId($quote,$customerId); // where `$customerId` is your `customer id`
$items=$customerQuote->getAllItems();
?>
```

Hope it will help 
Thanks

Comment: Would I be able to get is_active? I haven’t used this

Comment: Yes you can get is_active for that you have to use quote item collection.                                use Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory as   QuoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;

}
 $this->quoteFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1);

Comment: Let me know if my answer is helpful@Jack Brooks

Comment: Hi @ManishChaubey  I will get back to you soon as I tried this and thank you